# Optimize SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have created a view that returns data from more than one table using join. When I select from that view without using `Order By` clause, the time taken to execute that query is only about 1 second or less. But when I use `order by` with my select query, it takes about 27 seconds to return only the `top(15)` records from that view.

Here is my query that I run To get data from View

```
SELECT TOP(15) *
FROM V_transaction 
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
```

**Note** : total number of records that view has is about 300000

What can I change in my view's design to get better performance?

Comment: Does `time_stamp` have an index in the underlying table?

Comment: With no information as to the actual table schema and indexes on the underlying table, it's impossible to give you assistance. You need to provide all the necessary information for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

First thing that pops into mind is creating an index on `time_stamp` in the view.  If you don't want to/can't create an indexed view you could create an index on the column in the underlying table that you are getting that value from.  This should increase your queries performance.

If you are still having issues post the execution plan - this should show you exactly where/why your query is experiencing performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an extra column which stores the numbers of days + number of seconds for a each date record and then order by that column..